# Is there a trackball with pressure sensitivity like in a pen tablet?

Tags: hardware, drawing-tablet, hardware-recommendation

As for the title, is there a trackball with pressure feature for brushes in Photoshop? 
Many years ago I used a trackball in CAD/CAM software and now I'd like to use it in Photoshop retouching but I'love the pressure feature of a tablet.

Edit:

maybe is the wrong place to ask, but I just want to know if there is a trackball compatible with the configurations "shape dynamics 'or' color dynamics" for pressure-sensitive brushes in Photoshop as with graphic-tablets.
Excuse my broken English, but more than that I can not explain ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question, **I don't believe that this exists.**

I can't find anything about pressure sensitive trackballs. Unfortunately if you want an input that is pressure sensitive then tablets are probably the best way to go.

The only thing I could think of is trying to use a trackball and a tablet simultaneously (using the pen for pressure, and the trackball for movement). But I have no idea if that will really work. Or maybe there's something else that can simulate pressure while using the trackball.